# Fencing VM nodes

Tags: centos, vmware, cluster

I'm using VMware Workstation as my hypervisor. I want to create a cluster with two nodes and a sharing storage with FreeNAS.

My questions are around fencing.

- Is it possible to do it in this case?
- If yes please how to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this using VMware, at least it appear to be the case according to this article titled: [Fence Device and Agent Information for Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/site/node/28603).

As to setting it up I did find these 2 resources which are too long to include in an answer here so I'm only going to reference them. They come from a ProxMox tutorial (another virtualization technology) so the steps might deviate a bit but this should get you started.

- [Fencing](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Fencing)
- [Two-Node High Availability Cluster](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Two-Node_High_Availability_Cluster)